# Featherjs - board name ( dynamic ) as service name

Tags: feathersjs

I have the below line in expressjs . It handles all the user made boards

```
app.post('/:board_name(\\[a-z0-9]+)/:type(\\d{2}):tab(\\d{2}):id(\\d+)', board.postEntry)
```

It has board name ( which is dynamic and user creates it) , 2 digits type ,  2 digits tab and rest of the stuff is ID

**For example**

```
http://localhost/board1/1023202020
http://localhost/board2/1121202020
http://localhost/board3/1221202020
```

I am new to FeatherJs and I don't see any way I can create a service like this. 
Could some one help me to create a service to handle this kind of requests ( and also if possible applying filters and hooks ) ? Thank You .

```
app.use('/messages', myService);
const service = app.service('messages');
```

I tried the below , but it didn't help me

```
  app.use('/:board_name(\\[a-z0-9]+)/:type(\\d{2}):tab(\\d{2}):id(\\d+)', myService);
```

**Update**

Found the problems , If I remove the regex after boardname it is working fine .  . So the below one is working fine But want to find out what regex should I use after boardname for alphanumeric .

```
app.use('/:board_name/:type(\\d{2}):tab(\\d{2}):id(\\d+)', myService);
```

Comment: what is the "\\" for ? because when I try `/:board_name([a-z0-9]+)/:type` here http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ it worked.

Comment: Thank You @Jalil for your response .That solved the problem . I used \\ for escaping initially and didn't notice that caused the problem .  But if I remove the two backslashes for type or tab or for id it is breaking ( It is not working if I remove for them )